# How to set qrc compression settings in a qbs project?

Tags: qt, compression, flags, qbs, qresource

In a qmake based project, I could do this:

```
#QMAKE_RESOURCE_FLAGS += -threshold 0 -compress 1
```

But searching around, I don't seem to find how to do this for a qbs project. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported at the moment.

Comment: Any idea if and when then?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21256950)

Comment: @Rob That an answer says *is not currently supported, can not be, etc.* is also an answer.

Comment: @eyllanesc It's a comment. This response does not answer the question, "How?". It can't answer the questions as is. Only offering an alternative could be considered an answer.

Comment: @Rob is that if the solution does not exist, what should the answer be? For me it is: you can not.

Comment: @eyllanesc I already said. An answer does not exist but offering an alternative can be considered an answer if it provides a solution.

Comment: @Rob a response that indicates a "no" helps the OP to avoid wasting time and invest in finding another alternative, a response does not imply a solution, SO is a Q&A, solutions are not necessarily obtained. :-)

Comment: @dtech The best way to ensure that it happens (short of providing a patch yourself) is to create a task at bugreports.qt.io. Apparently, no one has needed this feature so far.

Comment: @rob I disagree. The question is perfectly fine, so there's nothing to clarify. The answer is also clear, and it is "you can't". It might not be satisfactory for the OP, but it is the truth.

Comment: @ChristianKandeler what is the motivation to cut out features that Qt already supports by not providing ways to access the settings via qbs?

Comment: I didn't say anything was wrong about the question.

Comment: @dtech Nothing was "cut out", it just wasn't added yet. Most likely it was left out for simplicity when doing the original proof of concept and then it was forgotten to add it later.

Comment: Never mind, seems like qbs is going the way of the dodo bird :D